# SwiftUI: Toggle 3 Buttons

Tags: swiftui

i would like to show 3 Buttons and depending on the selected kartenTyp the .buttonStyle(.bordered) should be set. I can't figure out how to resolve this.

```
HStack{
            Text("Kartentyp")
            Spacer()
            Button("Standard") {}
                .tint(Color.blue)
                .onTapGesture {
                    kartenTyp = 1
                }
            Button("Satelit") {}
                .tint(Color.blue)
                .onTapGesture {
                    kartenTyp = 2
                }
            Button("Hybried") {}
                .tint(Color.blue)
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                .onTapGesture {
                    kartenTyp = 3
                }
            
        }
```

[Code Example with preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLBvC.png)

Comment: an example for the last one `buttonStyle(kartenTyp == 3 ? .bordered : .automatic)`

Comment: This is not working it gives the Error Type 'ButtonStyle' has no member 'bordered' and 'automatic'

Comment: I think in this situation, you need to create your own `ButtonStyle` that has the logic inside to choose between the two, and then use that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom `ViewModifier`, as an alternative to using a `ButtonStyle`.
Such as in this example code:

```
struct StyleMod: ViewModifier {
    let isBordered: Bool
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if isBordered {
            content.buttonStyle(.bordered)
        } else {
            content.buttonStyle(.plain)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var kartenTyp = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text("\(kartenTyp)")
            Spacer()
            Button("Standard") {kartenTyp = 1}
                .tint(Color.blue)
                .modifier(StyleMod(isBordered: kartenTyp == 1))
            
            Button("Satelit") {kartenTyp = 2}
                .tint(Color.blue)
                .modifier(StyleMod(isBordered: kartenTyp == 2))
            
            Button("Hybried") {kartenTyp = 3}
                .tint(Color.blue)
                .modifier(StyleMod(isBordered: kartenTyp == 3))
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```